# Java reflection - check is assignable from classmetadata

Tags: java, reflection

ok - I am walking a resource tree looking for classes that extend a particular super class, *possibly not directly* - I have code that works, but I'm having to resolve a concrete class, and I'm just wondering whether the same thing is possible without actually resolving the class - here is my working function:

```
 private static <T> boolean checkInherits(Class<T> superClass, ClassMetadata classInformation)
{
    try
    {
        Class<?> theClass = Class.forName(classInformation.getClassName());
        return superClass.isAssignableFrom( theClass );
    }
    catch (Throwable theException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So - is it possible to do that without using class.forName()?   ie straight from the class metadata?

Comment: What is `ClassMetadata`? What library does it come from (not the standard API)? There are various APIs that have a class with this name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way. A (non-`final`) class `Foo` cannot "know" about all of its (direct or indirect) subclasses because anyone can create a class that extends `Foo`. Hence, you can only learn about subclass relationships once you have both `Class` objects.

Assuming `ClassMetadata` is from the Spring framework ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/type/ClassMetadata.html)), you *could* use `.getSuperClassName()` to get the `String` representation of the superclass, but this won't solve your problem if the subclass relationship isn't direct. The only way to get the `Class` object from a `ClassMetadata` is by using `Class.forName(classInformation.getClassName())`, exactly as you've already done.